# Create browse-files Button in quickly app

Tags: 12.04, quickly

How can i set the "add button" i have created using **quickly application developer** to pop up a regular "browse to open files" window whenever it is clicked ? I also want to display the selected image at the display area below the button named imageArea. if someone could help me with that.

```
self.addButton = self.builder.get_object("addButton")

def on_addButton_clicked(self, widget):
    (take me to browse an image)
    (display the selected image)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`FileChooserDialog`](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html#filechooserdialog).

It should look something like this (untested):

```
    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", self._parentwindow,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
         Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

    filter_img = gtk.FileFilter()
    filter_img.set_name("Images")
    filter_img.add_pixbuf_formats()
    dialog.add_filter(filter_img)

    response = dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        imagefile = dialog.get_filename()
        self.imagewidget.set_from_file(imagefile)
    dialog.destroy()
```

Setting an image can be done in various other ways than my example, look at the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkImage.html) for more information.